# QT Spim Mips programming - inputting a character into a string

Tags: qt, mips, spim

How would I add on a letter into a string. For instance, I have:

```
str: .asciiz "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

I want to add the letter a to the end of the string to make it display  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza" when I print out the string.

I've tried

```
la $t0, str
lb $t1, 0($t0)
add $t0, $t0, 25
sb $t2, 1($t0)    # assume that $t2 contains the character a
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't just grow a string without having space for it to grow *into*. In this case you'd be overwriting the NULL terminator with an `'a'`, which can cause all sorts of problems later on.

You could allocate some extra space following the string:

```
str: .asciiz "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
extra_space: .space 32
```

And then adding an `'a'` at the end could be done like so:

```
la  $t0,str+26
li  $t1,'a'
sb  $t1,($t0)     # append an 'a' to the string
sb  $zero,1($t0)  # add a NULL terminator after the 'a'
```