# How to increment byte counter in QT Spim

Tags: mips, spim

For instance, I have a program with this string:

```
str: .asciiz "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Then I put another letter at the end of the string by doing:

```
la $t0, str
sb $t1, 26($t0) # the letter a  is stored into $t1
```

This makes the editted str to be:

```
str: .asciiz "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"
```

My question is how do I increment that number 26, to 27 because I have a loop that keeps accepting user inputted characters and adding it to the end of the string, but I keep replacing the last letter of the string with the new letter.  I want to increment the 26 by 1 every time it loops once so that the string keeps lengthening, not being replaced by other letters.  The only thing I can think of is

```
sb $t1, $t2($t0)
add $t2, $t2, 1
```

which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> This makes the editted str to be:

```
str: .asciiz "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"
```

That's not entirely true (see [my answer for your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16186730/1524450)). `.asciiz` implies a NULL-terminated string, but you just overwrote the NULL terminator with an `'a'`.

---

```
add $t2, $t2, 1
```

> which doesn't work.

The `add` instruction adds registers together. Use `addi` or `addiu` if you want to add an immediate value to a register. For example:

```
addiu $t2,$t2,1  # add 1 to $t2, ignoring potential overflows
```